# $S^tDS$ positive semidefinite if $D$ is so

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite

Let $\mu_i \in \mathbb{R}_{\ge0}$, $i=1,...,n$, and $D=(\delta_{ij}\mu_i)\in\text{M}(n,\mathbb{R})$.

$D$ itself is surely positve semidefinite, this can be proved via prinipal minors.

But why is $S^tDS$ also positive semidefinite for a matrix $S$ with real entries? Is there a proof using principal minors?

Comment: how about looking at $x^T S^T D S^T x$?

Comment: Could you explain please? I guess you mean $x^tS^tDSx=(Sx)^tDSx$?

Comment: right, why the interest in principal minors?

Comment: Just thought it would be easier using positive semidefinte <=> all principal minors $\ge 0$.